# replacing column names using .loc or df.repalce

Tags: python, pandas

```
for fidx, compare in enumerate(focus_df.columns):
    for idx,c in enumerate(col_names_df['Column']):
        if compare in c:
            focus_df.columns[fidx] = col_names_df['Description'][idx]
```

This above code throws an error:

> Index does not support mutable operations

How can I use df.replace in this case ? Will .loc work ?

Comment: I think you need to have the columns object as a regular list to enable indexing like so `list(focus_df.columns)[fidx]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking to rename columns using values from other dataframe. You can use [DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) for this:

```py
focus_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,]], columns=["Sun"])
print(focus_df)
+-----+
| Sun |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+


col_names_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["Sunday","Sunday is holiday"]], columns=["Column", "Description"])
print(col_names_df)
+--------+-------------------+
| Column |       Description |
+--------+-------------------+
| Sunday | Sunday is holiday |
+--------+-------------------+


for fidx, compare in enumerate(focus_df.columns):
    for idx,c in enumerate(col_names_df["Column"]):
        if compare in c:
            focus_df = focus_df.rename(columns={focus_df.columns[fidx]: col_names_df["Description"][idx]})
# 
print(focus_df)
+-------------------+
| Sunday is holiday |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
```